# Unbalanced panel - parallel trends assumption?

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference

I am running a difference in difference model to evaluate the causal impact of a policy on deforestation. I have a sample of treated communities, with heterogeneous starting points, as well as info of the untreated areas. The policy has been ongoing since the 2000, so I am now checking the trends before the policy.

My question is with regards to testing the parallel trends assumption, and the data I have available. It is a very unbalanced panel, that starts from 1970s to 1999, some regions have only 3 pre-policy points, others 4, 5 or 6, all in all tho, all have at-least 3 pre/policy observations for all and one of those is very close to the policy application. Given that the reason for the missing information is random/exogenous (cloud cover and available satellite information for places/years) that does not seem to be an issue. Is the unbalanced nature of my pre-policy data much of an issue? should I maybe do interpolation?

Comment: Do you observe communities with missing time information in the periods *immediately before* the shock? In other words, a situation where a community has pre-policy data in 1990, 1991, and 1992 but the start of the treatment is in, say, 1999?

Comment: First batch  of policy started on 2000, (and then 2001,2, etc). For all treated and non treated areas,  regardless of starting point of the policy , I have at least an observation in 1997,8, or 9 - but not 3 data points that are next to each other. For example I have some individuals with 68,77,84,91 and 98.  Another group individuals has 70, 86, 98.. So if I take into account all pre-policy observations, I have an observations that cover 63, 68, 70, 73, 77, 84, 85, 86, 90, 91, 97, 98 and 99, but not a single area covers all of this years.

Comment: So from 1991 through 1997, all regions have missing information? Also, how many regions are in each group?

Comment: yeah from 1991 through  1997 there are missing yearsbut with certainty all regions have an observation close to the date of the launch of the policy. There are are 9 "estuaries" I am observing, in which my whole sample (94 communities) are located.